# ActiveRecord query involving .path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Not sure how to do this query.   I can only get the full path of a song_file, so I'm trying to match it with the path of an attachment, like:

```
@song = Song.where("song_file.path = ?", song_path).to_a.first
```

But it doesn't work, as it's not an attribute.   Wondering if there's another option?

update:

song_file is actually a paperclip interpolation, so i don't know how to dig that out of a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the filename out of your path which would most probably be at the end and try matching that like:

```
Song.where(song_file_name: song_file_name).first
```

Also, wby you converting it to array and fetching first from it? Try instead `Song.find_by_song_file_name(song_file_name)`

Comment: I appreciate that man.   I'm trying to dig out info from jPlayer when a song starts and is 75% done, and I was hoping to find the song playing by comparing the paths, but they don't match up.   so i threw some extra fields on the playlist array hash, and found it by triggering events, and digging in there deep to pull out the info, like event.jPlayer.status.media.band